# XML serialize without overwriting

Tags: c#, xml

How can I serialize data to xml without overwriting previous data?
In this code I am able to make XML file but when I run this again I overwrite what I saved previously:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ActorGenerator
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {                  
        Console.Write("How many actors you want to add? ");
        int max = 0;
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            int x = i + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("////////////////////////ACTOR" + x + "/////////////////////////////////");


            Actor actor1 = new Actor();
            Console.Write("NAME (string): ");  actor1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("AGE (int): "); actor1.Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("FOCUS (string): "); actor1.Focus = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("PRICE (int): "); actor1.Price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("CONTRACTED (true/false): "); actor1.Contracted = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("PLAYING IN FILM (true/false): "); actor1.PlayingInFilm = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("SKILL (int): "); actor1.Skill = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            SerializeToXML(actor1);
        }
    }

    static public void SerializeToXML(Actor actor)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Actor));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\users\Desktop\actor.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, actor);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}

public class Actor
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Focus { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool Contracted { get; set; }
    public bool PlayingInFilm { get; set; }
    public int Skill { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Also, how can I read XML data and store it into variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should create a `List<Actor>` - you can then start with a list of one entry, serialize that list, then next time round *deserialize* the list, add an actor, and then serialize again so you'll have two entries in the list the following time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To read the data, load the file to a StreamReader, and then use the Deserialize method on the serializer:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Actor));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\users\Desktop\actor.xml");
Actor actor = (Actor)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

(Assuming you only have one actor you're saving in the XML file)
To not overwrite, I recommend you read the data, as described above, and then update the object, and then finally write to the XML file.  This way you preserve what was originally in the XML file as desired.

(Assuming you want many actors in the XML file)
You likely want to serialize a List rather than just Actor.  If so, you can still read the data in (cast to List instead), update the list as necessary, then serialize back out to the XML file.

PS: Instead of using "Close" on your readers/writers, and other IDisposable objects, I recommend you use the "using" statement in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a true into your constructor for the StreamWriter

```
static public void SerializeToXML(Actor actor)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Actor));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\users\Desktop\actor.xml",true);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, actor);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

As far as fixing the Xml, you could use Linq To XML http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx to create valid XML and save it to file in one shot

Comment: You think appending XML will be a success?

Comment: I think it'll stop the file being overwritten, which is what they asked. They're overwriting the file in the foreach on each pass.

Comment: But it won't create valid XML. So, whereas it does prevent overwriting, it doesn't really solve the problem.